# MacOS 10.5.6 I didn't use Game Center Entitlement and Running Smoothly. I need check old version MacOS 10.15.3 but I couldn't

Tags: macos, game-center, macos-catalina, xamarin.mac

I have some problems. I use **XAMARIN.MAC, C#.** I wrote an App for Mac OS x 10.15... But they have rejected It. I couldn't found any results.

> I tried MacOs 10.15.5 and MacOs 10.15.6 They are physical machines Mac
> Air and Mac Pro... Running Smoothly...

**My entitlement list Is**
com.apple.security.app-sandbox,
com.apple.security.network.client,
com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write, com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit,
**Do they belong to the game center?** (I'm not sure) ... **However, I saw under the Identifier Default clicked Game Center checkbox, I couldn't change It because It is the default.**

Please follow Apple Reject Message... **Do you have any idea or recommendations?**

Apple Message is
Guideline 2.1 - Performance

Your app crashed on Mac running macOS 10.15.3 when we:
Launch app (clean install)
Click Analysis Window
Click Start Analysis
App immediately quits
No crash log produced

> I tried Its work correctly on macOS 10.15.5 and 10.15.6. Running
> Smoothly. **What should I do to test the version and see what is wrong?
> (They are said 10.15.3 crash It)** Your app contains the Game Center
> entitlement, but it does not link against the GameKit framework.

Apple Message is
Next Steps

If you would like to include Game Center, please link against the GameKit framework and submit an updated binary.

Resources

For information on Game Center, please review the Game Center Programming Guide.

> **I didn't use Game Center Emtlement** It but I'm not sure. **How can I detect?**, Also, I don't
> need Game Center.
> **My entitlement list Is**

com.apple.security.app-sandbox,
com.apple.security.network.client,
com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write, com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit,

Best Wishes,
Volkan

Comment: MacOS is not really my world. But IMO your post requires better formatting for readability and maybe some code samples. Use code fences to show what you types and what system error messages were. This way you have a better chance of attracting someone who understands your question and provide an answer to it.

Comment: using "com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit" is suspicious at best and you haven't said a word on why.

Answer (score 0):

You can start investigating by looking if your app links against GameKit

```
otool -L yourappname.app/Contents/MacOS/yourappname | grep GameKit
```

Then if you can see any output you might want to configure linking options and try again.